# How to make the Logitech 300s move wider?

Tags: mojave, mouse

[image]

I am using an wired mouse Logitech 300s (As seen in the screenshot)

Whenever I move the mouse from edge to edge of the mouse pad, the cursor only moved about slightly over 1/2 of the way on the monitor.

I really want the mouse cursor move a longer distance. Is there any way I can fine tune it?

EDIT:

Add screen shot of Mouse pane in System Preferences

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the G8 button on the mouse to switch to "Productivity" profile. The light on the side will change to blue, and the mouse will travel longer distance when moving from side to side.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences - Mouse. Click on the "Point and Click" tab. In the middle of this pane is a slider for Tracking Speed.  By moving the slider to the right to make it faster will do what you want.  See the image below.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the same screen. Probably because mine is not an Apple mouse. I have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: The slider has the same effect as in your control panel. The one thing you can't control without a 3rd party mouse controller is the amount of acceleration;  the difference between how far it moves when you drag slowly, or if you whip the mouse across.

Comment: I don't see the same screen.

Comment: You still have a Tracking Speed slider.  That should do it!